# Jquery dataTable Column Update and Export

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, tabletools

My problem is, once the dataTable is loaded I am updating certain column with new values and it is working perfectly. But when i try to export the table, the exported data has only the old values and not the new ones.  Also, even if I try to perform search based on my new values, it says no data available.

Any workarounds would be a great help.

```js
//Adding a button

"oTableTools": {
  "aButtons": [
    {
      "sExtends": "xls",
      "sButtonText": "Export data as CSV",
      "mColumns": "visible"
    }
  ]
}

// Updating the column
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
oTable.fnUpdate(colData, $("tr#"+i)[0],10); //Updating
oTable.fnDraw(); // Since doing an update alone is not working, I tried to draw the table again
```

Comment: could you provide us with a fiddle ?

Comment: Hi, here is the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/ronnjoe/j180npnq/ . Please ignore the version warning while loading the page

Comment: I understand that there is no export option, but if you notice even the search would give you a old results. If it can work on search then I am sure it would definitely work  for export as both are fetching the data from the table

Comment: something is fishy with that fiddle. It causes my browser to freeze for a long time. So, I am sorry but I am not gonna investigate it.

Comment: Hey, but it works fine for me.. Anyways thanks for looking into it

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the data that is being filtered on is not being updated when the display data is being updated.
Try this for your `updateColumn` function:

```
function updateColumn(){
    var oTable = $("#dashboard").dataTable();

    oTable.fnDeleteRow(1);
    oTable.fnAddData({
        "name":"Jerald",
        "id":"2",
        "dep":"Mech" });
    oTable.fnDraw(true); //Redraw
}
```

Deleting the row and adding a new one with the updated information should update the filter data as well.

You also have another problem with your script.  You are calling your `updateColumn` function on every draw, which is unnecessary.  Try moving it so it is only called once.

Here is a working jsFiddle to illustrate these changes: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzva6u0g/)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. The datatable which I used in the fiddle is just an example. In my actual scenario I have around 100's of rows, which would render from an ajax request. later once the dataTable finished loading I start making another ajax request to fill a particular column for all the rows with their id's. So in this case i cannot delete all the rows and add it again.